# Pear upgrade all is not working in Ubuntu

Tags: upgrade, php

When I try to upgrade Pear It shows message on terminal as follows

```
Will upgrade channel://pear.php.net/xml_util
Will upgrade channel://pear.php.net/pear
Will upgrade channel://pear.php.net/structures_graph
WARNING: channel "pear.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pear channel-update pear.php.net" to update
WARNING: "pear/Console_Getopt" is deprecated in favor of "pear/Console_GetoptPlus"
pear/PEAR dependency package "pear/Structures_Graph" downloaded version 1.1.0 is not the recommended version 1.0.4, but may be compatible, use --force to install
pear/PEAR dependency package "pear/XML_Util" downloaded version 1.3.0 is not the recommended version 1.2.3, but may be compatible, use --force to install
pear/pear dependency package "pear/XML_Util" downloaded version 1.3.0 is not the recommended version 1.2.1, but may be compatible, use --force to install
pear/XML_Util cannot be installed, conflicts with installed packages
pear/pear dependency package "pear/Structures_Graph" downloaded version 1.1.0 is not the recommended version 1.0.4, but may be compatible, use --force to install
pear/Structures_Graph cannot be installed, conflicts with installed packages
No valid packages found
upgrade-all failed
```